# How to disable CRM 2011 Xrm caching?

Tags: caching, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, xrm

I have problem with crm 2011 caching. I don't need it, but I don't know how to disable it.

First I generate this:

> CrmSvcUtil.exe
>   /codeCustomization:"Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration.CodeCustomization,
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration" /out:Outputcs
>   /url:https://crmaddress/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc
>   /username:usr/password:pw 
>   /namespace:ns/serviceContextName:XrmServiceContext

then I have the following code:

```
   private XrmServiceContext _crmService;

    public CrmWS()
    {
        CrmConnection _connection = new CrmConnection();
        _connection.ServiceUri = new Uri("https://url");

        ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();
        credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("1","2","3"); 
        _connection.ClientCredentials = credentials;
        _connection.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "1";
        _connection.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "2";
        _crmService = new XrmServiceContext(_connection);

       var l = _crmService.EntitySet.where(m => m.name == "a").ToList();
    }
```

What should I do to turn off caching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the service in your configuration file:

```
  <microsoft.xrm.client>   
    <services>
      <add name="Xrm" type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.OrganizationService, Microsoft.Xrm.Client"/>
    </services>
  </microsoft.xrm.client>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another bypass I found which can be used, its not perfect and people might give me bad reviews.

But you can always use a query which always changes with a random number or other random code:

```
Random r = new Random();
int rInt = r.Next(-100000000, 100000000);
var l = _crmService.EntitySet.where(m => m.name == "a" &&  m.name!=rInt.ToString()).ToList();
```